# don't understand complex Ruby code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently reading Rails 3 In Action.  There is code that I was wondering if someone could explain to me.  I'm having a hard time understanding it:

```
    scope :readable_by, lambda { |user| joins(:permissions).where(permissions: { action: "view", user_id: user.id })}
```

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a [Rails scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).  It essentially creates a class method called `.readable_by(user)` that does a SQL join on the permissions table and returns records where the `action` column value is "view" and the `user_id` column value equals `user.id`.

It could be used like so (assuming it's defined in the `Comments` model):

```
readable_comments = Comments.readable_by(current_user)
```

A simple scope that does nothing is this:

```
scope :my_scope_name, lambda {}
```

A scope that accepts a parameter is this:

```
scope :my_scope_name, lambda { |my_parameter| }
```

And then the above scope uses some [ActiveRecord finder methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database), specifically `joins` and `where`.

Comment: Good answer. For completeness, please also explain `lambda` here.

Comment: Good idea.  A `lambda` is an anonymous function.  Beyond that I'll defer to the docs (explained in the Proc object): http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html